# Use of uninitialised value

Tags: perl

I am trying to debug this warning in the following piece of code.

> Use of uninitiated value $aprs_position in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/bin/arsed line 207.

```
foreach my $ent ( @upd_q ) {

    my $aprs_position = Ham::APRS::FAP::make_position(
        $ent->{'latitude'},
        $ent->{'longitude'},
        -1,        # speed
        -1,        # course
        -10000,    # altitude
        ( defined $ent->{'symbol'} ) ? $ent->{'symbol'} : '/[',    # symbol
        1,                                                         # compression
        0                                                          # no ambiguity
    );                                                             

    print "$aprs_position\n";

    my $packet = sprintf( '%s>APTR01:!%s', $ent->{'callsign'}, $aprs_position );

    print "$packet\n";

    if ( $aprs_enable == 1 ) {

        my $ok = $is->sendline( $packet );

        if ( ! $ok ) {
            $is->disconnect();
```

It appears that there is either an error in the value coming back from `Ham::APRS::FAP::make_position` or possibly a syntax error?

What's the best way to start debugging this please?

Comment: Which line is 207?

Comment: @shawnhcorey: It can only be `print "$aprs_position\n"` if it's within the code sample.

Comment: @Borodin No, it appears twice in the above code. Without knowing which line is reporting the error, it cannot be solved.

Comment: @shawnhcorey: The second occurrence isn't "in concatenation (.) or string". Either way, the problem is that `$aprs_position` is `undef`, so the value returned by `make_position` is in error.

Comment: @AndyK: By the way, if you are running Perl v5.10 or better then `( defined $ent->{'symbol'} ) ? $ent->{'symbol'} : '/['` can be written as `$ent->{symbol} // '/['`

Answer (score 2):

It's not a syntax error (if it was, your code wouldn't run at all), so you're right that you're not getting what you expect back from your call to `Ham::APRS::FAP::make_position()`.

Looking at [the code for the subroutine](https://metacpan.org/source/HESSU/Ham-APRS-FAP-1.20/FAP.pm#L3312), I see a couple of things that would cause it to return `undef`, but the author obviously doesn't believe in displaying a warning to tell you exactly what you've got wrong.

If it was me, I'd use the debugger to trace the execution of that subroutine to see where it goes wrong. I suspect it's something in the code that deals with `$symbols`, but I don't know what value you're passing there.

I'd also add something like this after the line that is supposed to set that variable.

```
die 'Undefined value for $aprs_position' unless defined $aprs_position;
```

Comment: @AndyK: Yes. Essentially, one of the parameters to the function call is out of bounds, and there is no easy way to tell which one. (It's a very oddly-written module altogether.) If you're not familiar with the debugger then you could try adding a series of `print` statements to show the values that you're passing to `make_position`.